# Skype URI: как послать сообщение?

Tags: c#, uri, skype

Доброго времени суток всем.

Сейчас Microsoft убили все старые библиотеки для работы со скайпом, и теперь у меня вопрос, а какие все же есть способы отправки сообщений в скайп из server side? Или теперь это возможно только client side and JavaScript?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Через `libpurple` и плагин [SkypeWeb](https://github.com/EionRobb/skype4pidgin/tree/master/skypeweb) пока работает без проблем.

Авторы плагина честно предупреждают, что его использование - нарушение TOS и может повести за собой бессрочный бан аккаунта.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь  [этим](http://habrahabr.ru/post/232805/) способом установки старого skype и используйте Api сколько угодно.

Comment: -> Дополнение от 11.08.2014: рецепт перестал работать, авторизация слетает в течение нескольких секунд после запуска.

Comment: @beliy26rus, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.